# How to make a list item that's clicked on change color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I currently have an UL list structure and i'd like to make the selected item's background change, thus giving confirmation which was selected. I want to do it in a click JQuery method. That's currently the code I have, which select and gets the necessary data, associated with my items in the list. I have configured a CSS for the first child and I want to make the selected item the list's first child, inside this function. The function does a few things, but they're irrelevant to the question, hence why I've removed them.

[Picture of my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3G49.png)

```
    $(document).on('click', 'li.msg-user-name-wrap', function() {

                clearInterval(loadTimer);
                var otheridFromSearch = $(this).data('profileid');
                var searchImage = $(this).find('.msg-user-photo img').attr('src');
                var searchName = $(this).find('.msg-user-name').text();
                $('.users-right-pro-pic img').attr('src', searchImage);
                $('.users-right-pro-name').text(searchName);
                $('.user-info').attr("data-otherid", otheridFromSearch);
                xyz(useridd, otheridFromSearch, abc);

                $.post('http://localhost/facebook/core/ajax/message.php', {
                    showmsg: otheridFromSearch,
                    yourid: useridForAjax
                }, function(data) {
                    $('.msg-box').html(data);
                    $('.user-show').empty();
                    $('.top-msg-user-photo img').attr('src', searchImage);
                    $('.top-msg-user-name').text(searchName);
                    scrollItself();
                })

                if (!intervalId) {
                    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                        loadMessageFromSearch(useridForAjax, otheridFromSearch);
                    }, 1000);
                    clearInterval(intervalIdtwo);
                    intervalIdtwo = null;
                } else if (!intervalIdtwo) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    intervalId = null;
                    intervalIdtwo = setInterval(function() {
                        loadMessageFromSearch(useridForAjax, otheridFromSearch);
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    alert('Nothing found');
                }

            })
```

Comment: can add some of your codes please

Comment: `this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this.parentNode.firstChild)`

Comment: Code edited as requested,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to detect a click on an item, and then move that item in the first place:

```js
$("ul > li").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

```css
li:first-child { background: yellow }
ul { cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
   <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

If you don't want to change the order, but just highlight the most recently selected item, then you cannot use `first-child` as CSS selector, as "first" really means first in order. Then instead you must mark the selected item in some other way (than moving it), for example by giving it a certain class attribute:

```js
$("ul > li").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
li.selected { background: yellow }
ul { cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
   <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have added a picture of my system. My idea is to make the background of Martin Trifonov grey when I click on it, while making the Georgi Kolev's box white. The color is set as a css property of the first-child.

Comment: By including your code at the beginning of my click function, the background changes, but so do the order of the users, so the checked one is always on top. Is there a way to keep them in their position but also declare first child or I'll need to use a different method for the background color?

Comment: "first-child" really refers to order. So if that is not what you want you'll have to use a different way in CSS to identify the selected item. See addition to my answer. Note that then the title of your question is misleading...

Comment: Thank you for the addition. I am just getting into web development and all this is new to me so I must've not understood the first child argument properly. I have added an addition to my post with the method I was able to come up with on my own, don't know if it's the smartest way to do it though.

Comment: Using css styles directly on the element like you did will also work. It is best practice however to define css classes for styling and then use those. NB: questions should not contain answers. If you want you can post an answer with that solution.

Comment: Rectified. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As I had misunderstood the `first-order` property, I came up with this code snippet to do what I needed, where `msg-user-add` is the parent of my list: it's the class I use to populate the items of the list.

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul.msg-user-add > li', function() {
    $('ul.msg-user-add > li').css("background-color", "#e9ebee");
    $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgray');
}
```

Comment: Good! It would be even better to (1) use CSS classes for the highlighting and not explicit styles (such as `background-color`), and (2) to not have to specify the default style of the non-selected items. Removing the highlighting style should be enough. This way you make your code easier to maintain on the day that you want to change the style of your page. It is also a pity you have to specify "msg-user-add" twice in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(document).on('click', 'li.msg-user-name-wrap', function() {
         $(this).css({'background': '#123456'});
   });
```

Comment: Using your answer, I was able to implement it in my code, so thanks!

Comment: I added a line of code to make the background transparent on everything else that's not clicked to fix this.